# Markdown rendering bug with inline code in Remarks

Tags: bug, documentation, markdown-rendering

Something is wrong with the Markdown rendering in [this topic's Remarks](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift/745/memory-management#t=201608090701465173544&a=remarks):

Source:

```
<h2>When to use the weak-keyword:</h2>
The `weak`-keyword should be used, if a referenced object may be deallocated during the lifetime of the object holding the reference.

<h2>When to use the unowned-keyword:</h2>
The `unowned`-keyword should be used, if a referenced object is not expected to be deallocated during the lifetime of the object holding the reference.
```

Rendered result:

[image]